# Nightwatch keeps giving 502 bad gateway

Tags: selenium, docker, nightwatch.js

I have a docker setup for nightwatch.js to run selenium tests through selenium grid for an express server application. When I just use a docker-compose up and then run my nightwatch tests manually after the server starts everything appears to start properly. If I run them as part of a containers command (ie. in my app server containers command or in a new container based on it that just runs nightwatch) then I get a 503 bad gateway error. I think there is a race condition in my docker setup that is causing this. Is there a way to guarantee my app server starts properly before running my nightwatch tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix your command with [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script (download it a and put in the image):

```
command: /wait-for-it.sh theotherservice:PORT -- your-previous-command
```

`wait-for-it.sh` will wait to the specified server:port to execute the command that is after `--`, so you can avoid the race condition.